# If for any $A \subseteq Y$, $\partial f^{-1}(A) \subseteq f^{-1}(\partial A)$ then $f$ is continuous.

Tags: general-topology

In Dugundji's textbook on Topology, question 8.10 in chapter III asks you to prove that if $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is a function between topological spaces, then $f$ is continuous iff $\partial f^{-1}(A) \subseteq f^{-1}(\partial A)$ for any $A \subseteq Y$. I was able to prove the sufficient condition but am currently banging my head against a wall trying to prove the necessary condition. I have found some errors in previous questions which made the question impossible to solve and so I am worried this is an untrue statement.

My question is this, is the equivalency true? If not, is there a counterexample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will show that $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed for all $C \subseteq Y$ closed. Given a closed set $C \subseteq Y$, we have
$$ \partial f^{-1}(C) \subseteq f^{-1}(\partial C) \subseteq f^{-1}(C), $$
where the first inclusion is the assumption, and the second one follows from $\partial C \subseteq C$, as $C$ is closed. Therefore, we get that $f^{-1}(C)$ contains all its boundary, and so $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed. This implies that $f$ is continuous, as required.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know $\partial A \subseteq A$ is equivalent to $A$ being closed.

Comment: It is a really useful characterization! The closed sets are the ones that contain all the boundary points, while the open sets are the ones that do not contain any boundary point. Try to prove it by yourself!

Comment: Yes, I see it from $\overline{A} = \partial A \cup Int(A)$ which shows $\overline{A} \subseteq A$ if $\partial A \subseteq A$.